# What's wrong on my Decrypt method translating it from .NET to Java?

Tags: java, .net, encryption

I'm bulding an application that Encrypt in .NET and decrypt on Android App.

To test the correcteness of .NET, I also develope the Decrypt method on .NET, which is basically:

```
public static byte[] DecryptStreamWithEmbeddedHash(Stream inputStream, string password)
{
    const int iterations = 10000;
    const string customSalt = "myCustomSalt";
    static HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorith = HashAlgorithmName.SHA256;
    byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password + customSalt);

    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        using (var keyDerivation = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations, hashAlgorith))
        {
            aesAlg.Key = keyDerivation.GetBytes(32);
            aesAlg.IV = keyDerivation.GetBytes(16);

            // read hash length
            byte[] hashLengthBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            inputStream.Read(hashLengthBytes, 0, sizeof(int));
            int hashLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(hashLengthBytes, 0);

            // read hash
            byte[] embeddedHash = new byte[hashLength];
            inputStream.Read(embeddedHash, 0, hashLength);

            // decrypt content
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputStream, aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                cryptoStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my attempt on Java:

```
public static byte[] decryptStreamWithEmbeddedHash(InputStream inputStream, String password) throws Exception {
    int iterations = 10000;
    String customSalt = "myCustomSalt";
    String hashAlgorithm = "SHA-256";
    byte[] salt = (password + customSalt).getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, 256);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(salt, 0, 16); // IV is the first 16 bytes of salt

    // read hash length
    byte[] hashLengthBytes = new byte[4]; // sizeof(int)
    inputStream.read(hashLengthBytes, 0, 4);
    int hashLength = ByteBuffer.wrap(hashLengthBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();

    // read hash
    byte[] embeddedHash = new byte[hashLength];
    inputStream.read(embeddedHash, 0, hashLength);

    // decrypt content
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    ByteArrayOutputStream decryptedStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (CipherInputStream cryptoStream = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int len;
        while ((len = cryptoStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            decryptedStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] decryptedData = decryptedStream.toByteArray();

    // verify hash
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm);
    byte[] calculatedHash = md.digest(decryptedData);
    if (!Arrays.equals(calculatedHash, embeddedHash)) {
        throw new Exception("Hash verification failed.");
    }

    return decryptedData;
}
```

but on:

```
while ((len = cryptoStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    decryptedStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

at some point I got this:`java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:1e00007b:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH`

Am I not really sure what's the concrete cause. Going in debug indexes and position of stream seems correct?

Any clues?

Comment: You use different digests in the PBKDF2 key derivation (SHA256 in the .NET code, SHA1 in the Java code).

Comment: @Topaco: uhm, I'm using String hashAlgorithm = "SHA-256" in Java, not SHA1? :O

Comment: Note that calling `Stream.Read` and ignoring the return value is also a really bad idea in general, too... (Likewise the equivalent in Java.)

Comment: I refer to `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1`.

Comment: @Topaco oh right, I see. Change to PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 "on the fly", but got the same error. Probably should be revisited even more...

Comment: Because this is not the only issue, e.g. the IV seems to be determined inconsistently. In the Java code as commented: *IV is the first 16 bytes of salt*, in the .NET code it is derived using the KDF.

Comment: @Topaco Hope to not entering the world of reinventing the wheel. Maybe there are already some piece of code in Java that does this? I believe its a common algorithm used for basic scenarios...

Comment: If the differences mentioned are eliminated, the Java code works for me. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PBKDF2 key derivation in both codes differs in 2 points:

- In the .NET code SHA256 is used, in the Java code SHA1.
- In the .NET code the key and IV are derived, in the Java code only the key. As IV the first 16 bytes of the salt are used.

So that the key derivation in the Java code is equivalent to that in the C# code, the following changes are required:

```java
...
// derive key and IV via PBKDF2/HMAC/SHA256
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");        // Fix 1: apply SHA 256
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, 256 + 128);     // Fix 2: derive key and IV
byte[] keyIv = factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
ByteBuffer keyIvBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(keyIv);
byte[] key = new byte[32];
keyIvBuffer.get(key);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
byte[] iv = new byte[16];
keyIvBuffer.get(iv);
...
```

Note that the C# code does not contain the part that compares the hash values. Maybe this part was simply not posted.
Also consider the comment on the `read()` calls in both codes: In general, a `read()` call is not guaranteed to return as much data as was requested. More robust is e.g. on the Java side [`readNBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readNBytes(int)).
Regarding the comparison of the hash values: Usually an HMAC (of the ciphertext) is used for authentication, see [*Encrypt-then-MAC*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/205).

---

Test (with a ciphertext that is successfully decrypted by the C# code):

```java
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(HexFormat.of().parseHex("20000000D7A8FBB307D7809469CA9ABCB0082E4F8D5651E46D3CDB762D02D0BF37C9E592682052AFDB5B011FCEDEBC9FBF65688ADB9C1D32551CDE3F505D35B693CAED7B189C1D6DAD14EFD5861DF1239CF1CB74")); 
byte[] decrypted = decryptStreamWithEmbeddedHash(bais, "my password");
System.out.println(new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: Tried with my own string: doesn't work on Java. [.NET (working)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DIkbtY) and [Java (not working)](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Xt1) Note: on Java I've used StringBuilder since hex is too long (max 2*16 I believe for generic String in Java). Is says `Hash verification failed`

Comment: Edit: no, it seems to works, just the "verify hash" is wrong. Thanks dude :)

Comment: @markzzz - The posted C# code doesn't implement any verification, which is why I had no reference and just blindly used SHA-256 in the Java code and my test data. Possibly the C# code doesn't verify at all (in which case the verification can be removed from the Java code as well)  or somewhere else and uses a different digest/logic (which then needs to be ported into the Java code accordingly). However, the decrypted data itself is identical in both codes, as you have already noted yourself.